# Create a tower frame with a Icosahedron

Tags: modeling

How can I create a multi-sided geometric (geodesic) polyhedrons, specially a Icosahedron.  Using this for a tower frame construction.

friendly regards

Jos

Answer (score 3):

In Edit > Preferences > Add-Ons, enable the shipped add-on 'Mesh: Extra Objects'.

Then it's <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solids.. and in the creation panel dropdown, 'Icosaohedron'.